# Custom off-topic close reason: Travel

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Each Stack Echange site can have three custom Off-Topic reasons to help closing questions. I propose one of this should be the following (based on @GaLa's [comment](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2598/can-you-use-provisional-uk-driving-license-abroad)):

> This question appears to be off-topic because it is about travel rather than expatriation. These questions should belong to [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Any suggestions?

Comment: The reason I posted this comment is that the question was good (I could not in good faith pretend it was unclear, subjective or whatnot) but did not need to be migrated because there was an exact duplicate on travel.SE already (I posted a link as well). It was meant to explain the rule to the OP (in particular to avoid further travel questions in the future) and make sure he or she knew about travel.

Comment: Can we discuss this again? It looks unlikely that we'll every graduate, having a custom close reason means you can get an automatic, well-written comment added to the question, we have the same functionality in Travel so the reasons given below (duplicate questions, migration of bad questons, etc.) already exist in the other direction.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, having a link in the close reason just leads people to go copy the question they just asked on site A and paste it into site B only to have an equally miserable experience. Even when you make the link point to a lot of guidance on what any particular community looks for in good questions, *people generally don't read*.

It's okay to link, but do it in a comment along with some other advice. At least 99% of the time, some other advice is sorely needed. *This might be a good fit on [link]our travel site[/link], however - [how do I tell this guy her question is a trainwreck?]*

Migration paths will be *strongly* considered once Expats graduates - for now, just continue moving stuff that is off topic here *and that Travel SE would actually appreciate* with the finesse that you've been using since you started.

Comment: I understand that migrating to Expats.SE would be a problem, but is there any reason why not to migrate from Expats.SE to Travel.SE? I think that having this migration path available to all would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

My concerns:

1. There is already a migration tool for questions like this (though since this is a beta, there isn't a clear path to travel for normal users yet)
2. Having a close reason substituting for migration may cause bad questions to get migrated (rule #1 of migrations: don't migrate crap)
3. It may cause users who have their questions closed to ask a second question on travel.se prior to the migration going through, causing duplicate questions
4. It doesn't explain how to actually improve the question if it is crap and doesn't get migrated as a result

None of these are deal-breakers to me, but I think this may be handled better with custom flags for posts that can be migrated, and the SE-wide generic close reasons if the question is just bad. Much more helpful to have a question closed as, *"Unclear what you're asking"* than *"This belongs on travel.se"* if it isn't ever going to be migrated.

Comment: The off-topic close reason should only be used for "good" questions that are in fact off-topic. All SE sites have up to 3 sites which off-topic questions can be redirected to so this isn't unique to us.

Comment: @StrongBad, more than aware of how the system works as a mod on [workplace.se] who has gone through this there. While **I** know how the system works, many people who don't may use it for bad questions, confusing both them and the person whose question is closed.

Comment: +1 We already had several duplicates because travel questions got closed before they could be migrated and ended up being asked twice.

Comment: The reason I posted this comment is that the question was good (I could not in good faith pretend it was unclear, subjective or whatnot) but did not need to be migrated because there was an exact duplicate on travel.SE already. I don't see any good solution for this (admittedly somewhat unusual) situation.

Comment: We also had [one not so good question](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2559/moving-to-uk-i-will-be-going-as-dependent-visa-how-to-approach-an-employer-for-a) (IMO) that came straight from an identical travel question that was closed as “off-topic” with a link to expatriates.